# not able to send email from jsp using gmail's smtp server

Tags: jsp, email, smtp, gmail

I am new to jsp, I am trying to send email from a jsp page, but it fails without any stacktrace. Here is the code I tried,

```html
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%
 
    //username for abc@gmail.com will be "abc"
    String username = "abc";
    String password = "password";
    String result = null;
 
    try {
         
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
 
        Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("sender_username","sender_password");
                }
        });
 
        emailSession.setDebug(true);
        Message message = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(
                "sender_username@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("test123@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Test mail from Java");
        message.setText("Hello. this is a test");
 
        Transport transport = emailSession.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
 
        result = "Successfully sent email";

       } catch (MessagingException e) {
        result = "Unable to send email";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Send Email using JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
    </center>
    <p align="center">
        <%
            out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
        %>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have taken it from an blog/tutorial page. Since it is not printing the stack trace, I couldn't see where it is failing as well. It fails as 
" Result: Unable to send email "

Answer (score 0):

hope this work for you.

```
     final String username = "chandrasekar@gmail.com";//from which you want to send mail
    final String password = "chandra@123";//password off your mail id 

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("chandrasekar@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("etc@gmail.com"));//whom you want to send mail
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. But it still fails without any stacktrace :( I added a print in exception which confirms it goes to the exception.

Comment: then there's problem of `jar`.. change the version of jar and then try again